Add column to existing dataframe based on condition to a few rows
table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] = value

i want to extend this condition where my value is a list of dict, it can have 1 dict, multiple dict or empty list.
i tried using
table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] = [list_of_dict] * len(sub_table)

it works if list of dict has more than 1 dicts but fails in case of 1 dict in list
solutions tried:
table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] = pd.Series([list_of_dict] * len(sub_table))
table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] = pd.Series([list_of_dict] * len(sub_table)).to_list()

none of them seem to work
eg
table = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A']})
sub_table_condition = table['Category'] == 'B'
# Example column name
col_name = 'Data'

# Example list of dictionaries
list_of_dicts = [{"Val": 100, "Reascon": "Reason 1"},
                 {"Val": 200, "Reascon": "Reason 2"}]


Do you want to copy the entire list_of_dicts value to each location specified by table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] or should each entry in list_of_dicts go to one of the rows specified by sub_table_condition?

Please provide some sample output data that illustrates your desired result.

@Nick, objective is to copy the entire list_of_dicts value to each location specified by given condition.

@sameer just a quick warning, be aware that using [list_of_dict] * len(sub_table) doesn't create copies of the dictionaries but rather sets the same dictionary in all matching rows. If you later plan to modify the dictionaries this is important to know ;)

First I think working with list/dictss in pandas is not good idea, but if really need is possible use this solution:
Create Series with index values from filtered original index, for count matched values is used sum of Trues values:
s = pd.Series([list_of_dicts] * sub_table_condition.sum(), 
              index=table.index[sub_table_condition])
table.loc[sub_table_condition, col_name] = s
print (table)
   ID Category                                               Data
0   1        A                                                NaN
1   2        B  [{'Val': 100, 'Reascon': 'Reason 1'}, {'Val': ...
2   3        A                                                NaN

How it working:
print (pd.Series([list_of_dicts] * sub_table_condition.sum(), 
                 index=table.index[sub_table_condition]))
1    [{'Val': 100, 'Reascon': 'Reason 1'}, {'Val': ...
dtype: object


You need to craft a Series with the correct indices, assignment will use index alignment automatically:
table.loc[sub_table_condition, 'col'] = pd.Series([list_of_dicts]*len(table),
                                                  index=table.index)

Output:
   ID Category                                                col
0   1        A                                                NaN
1   2        B  [{'Val': 100, 'Reascon': 'Reason 1'}, {'Val': ...
2   3        A                                                NaN

